# blinking error of an app made with next js and with Ant design components,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, antd

Every time I change the page that commented part, it overlaps the handler for a short moment.

```
<Layout>
      <Sider
        trigger={null}
        collapsible
        width={250}
        collapsed={collapsed}
        theme="light"
        className="custom_sidebar"
      >
        <div className="logo">
          <span>{collapsed ? "CO" : "COmmunity"}</span>
        </div>
        <Scrollbars
          renderView={(props) => <div {...props} className="custom_view" />}
        >
          <Menu
            theme={"light"}
            mode="inline"
            style={{ height: "100%", borderRight: 0 }}
            className={"hide-group-title"}
          >
           
            {propertyNavigation.map((menu: any) =>
              menu.submenu.length > 0 ? (
                <Menu.ItemGroup key={menu.key}>
                  {menu.submenu.map((subMenuFirst: any) =>
                    subMenuFirst.submenu.length > 0 ? (
                      <SubMenu
                        icon={
                          subMenuFirst.icon ? (
                            <Icon type={subMenuFirst?.icon} />
                          ) : null
                        }
                        key={subMenuFirst.key}
                        title={subMenuFirst.title}
                      >
                        {subMenuFirst.submenu.map((subMenuSecond: any) => (
                          <Menu.Item key={subMenuSecond.key}>
                            {subMenuSecond.icon ? (
                              <Icon type={subMenuSecond?.icon} />
                            ) : null}
                            <span>{subMenuSecond.title}</span>
                            <Link
                              onClick={() => closeMobileNav()}
                              href={subMenuSecond.path}
                            />
                          </Menu.Item>
                        ))}
                      </SubMenu>
                    ) : (
                      <Menu.Item key={subMenuFirst.key}>
                        {subMenuFirst.icon ? (
                          <Icon type={subMenuFirst.icon} />
                        ) : null}
                        <span>{subMenuFirst.title}</span>
                        <Link
                          onClick={() => closeMobileNav()}
                          href={subMenuFirst.path}
                        />
                      </Menu.Item>
                    )
                  )}
                </Menu.ItemGroup>
              ) : (
                <Menu.Item key={menu.key}>
                  {menu.icon ? <Icon type={menu?.icon} /> : null}
                  <span>{menu?.title}</span>
                  {menu.path ? (
                    <Link onClick={() => closeMobileNav()} href={menu.path} />
                  ) : null}
                </Menu.Item>
              )
            )}
            <Menu.Item>
              <LogoutOutlined />
              <span>Cerrar sesión</span>
              <Link onClick={handleLogout} href={""} />
            </Menu.Item>
          </Menu>
        </Scrollbars>
      </Sider>
      {/* 
      
      This part flashes and overlaps the sider for a moment


      <Layout>
        <Header style={{ background: "#040411" }}>
          {React.createElement(
            collapsed ? MenuUnfoldOutlined : MenuFoldOutlined,
            {
              className: "trigger",
              onClick: () => setCollapsed(!collapsed),
            }
          )}
        </Header>
        <Content
          style={{
            margin: "24px 16px",
          }}
        >
          {children}
        </Content>
      </Layout> */}

      
    </Layout>`
```

I want it not to overlap the sidebar every time I change the page. Please help!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! Sorry, but in its current state, your question might get downvoted or closed. Please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so people can help you better.